# create spinner from list of strings

Tags: android, spinner

I have a list of strings that I'm trying to pass to a spinner

my code is this :

```
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_details);
            ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerTitles);
```

where "spinnerTitles" is my List of strings

the problem is I'm getting an error of "the constructor is undefined for..."

how to solve this?

Comment: i think `this` not refer to Context of activity, maybe you are try to run this code in backThread or anyWhere else, use `Activity.this` if you are in thread and use `getActivity()` if you are in fragment or ..., if you want more help post more code to us

Comment: is my answer worked out?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

check the constructor Context `this` maybe it refers to your Fragment. change it to :

```
ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(YourActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerTitles);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
ArrayList items=new ArrayList();
    ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(Activity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
```